# Reformat pictures in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2010

How can I re-size and re-locate all images on different PowerPoint slides using Macro?

size: height - 4.95 inches and width - 9 inches
position: x - 0.5 inches and y - 1.75 inches

Answer (score 0):

This did it!

```
Sub reformat()
With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    .Height = 4.95 * 72
    .Width = 9 * 72
    .Left = 0.5 * 72
    .Top = 1.75 * 72
    .ZOrder msoSendToBack
End With
```

End Sub